# How do I handle file uploading on distributed application?

Tags: php, distributed-apps

I have photo uploading functionality in web application using PHP. Which is going to host as distributed application on many servers.

Now, problem is how should I handle that photo uploading functionality so, that photo can be available on all server? My application is in php.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an already existing platform to perform syncing. Most modern OSes support syncing, and you could also use external tools.

## At the OS level:

- You can use [rsync](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rsync) for *nix servers (plus, this has been ported to Windows too)
- [Here's a way](http://www.orcsweb.com/blog/rick/how-to-synchronize-files-between-windows-servers/) to do it between Windows servers

### Using external tools:

- [Goodsync enterprise](http://www.goodsync.com/enterprise/server)
- [Syncbreeze](http://www.syncbreeze.com/syncbreeze_sync_server.html)
- Under *nix, you could use [rsync](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rsync)
- [Here's a collection](http://mashable.com/2008/07/24/synching-files-and-folders/) of programs (free and paid) to do this
- You could use a cloud-based service like [Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/) in all your servers

## Using PHP:

- You could use [librsync](http://pecl.php.net/package/rsync)
- You could add an FTP/SSH server to each one of your distributed servers. Once a file is uploaded to one server, it can be uploaded via FTP to the others. PHP includes functionality for FTP - [check the FTP section in the PHP handbook](http://php.net/manual/en/book.ftp.php).
- Use FXP to transfer files between servers. [The KioobFTP class](http://sourceforge.net/projects/kioobftp/) can be used for this, as it implements FXP transfers