# handling file upload and serving in a distributed web application

Tags: file-upload, synchronization, web-deployment

I'm going to deploy a web application with multiple Pyramid application servers and nginx as a load balancer.

This application will have a feature for uploading files which should be available for downloading afterwards.
Total size of uploaded files may be very big so I'd like to deploy a separate file webserver to serve these static files. (this is one reason why I don't like rsync solution proposed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17022047/how-do-i-handle-file-uploading-on-distributed-application)).

What is the best solution to handle file upload and syncronization in this case? I was thinking about NFS or something like that, but I'm not sure it is a good way to solve the problem. I suppose there must be some best-practices here or even a tool or library for these purposes.

UPDATE:
I don't want use cloud services like Dropbox, it would be nicer to find some syncronization solution inside the network segment.

UPDATE2:
I finished with setting up NFS, for now it works perfectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

not really a python or pyramid related question. But, you should investigate distributed file systems and CDN's both of which are for this kind of thing. [gridfs](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/faq/developers/#faq-developers-when-to-use-gridfs) is easy enough to get going with. But there are plenty of other options. Both Amazon and Google have similar services.

Comment: Thank you for you reply. I would prefer not to pack files in some "containers" like databases etc... Distributed FS seem fine but I'm just curious about best practices and obstacles that I should be aware about.

Comment: considering that amazon and google (being 2 of the more popular cloud providers) provide a distributed fs solution similar to gridfs, I would consider those things best practices. the choice becomes whether you want the hosting headache or not. livejournal did it with mogilefs back in the day, the same kind of idea.